# Developing with everyauth locally

Tags: everyauth

I want the Node `everyauth` module to work locally with Twitter (say). (I have got it working online, but not locally.) Following [this tutorial](http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/26-starting-with-everyauth.html#video) (see around 5:00) I have modified `/etc/hosts` and added the line

> 127.0.0.1 http://myExampleWebsite.com

I have also added the line

> 127.0.0.1   localhost local.host

as suggested in the [official readme file](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/blob/master/README.md). However,

> local.host:3000/auth/twitter

errors out after a few seconds with

> Error: Step getRequestToken of `twitter` module timed out.

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a hosts/callback problem to me. getRequestToken() is the initial call to Twitter's OAuth API, which happens before the user has authenticated with Twitter and before they're redirected back to your app (at which point your hosts file and callback URL become relevant). I'd check your configuration, make sure you have the right oauth keys, etc. I'd also check your node version (both online and on your dev machine) because I think everyauth has a few compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this same thing.  It's kind of tricky, and consensus seems to be that you should either set up two Twitter apps (one for local use and one for public use) or just be prepared to change your Twitter app's "callback URL" when your node app goes live.

In my case, I didn't need to modify my hosts file, but rather I changed the "callback URL" in my Twitter app to the following:

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback`

If you're using the default everyauth callback configuration, it's automatically set to accept callbacks at `/auth/twitter/callback`.  No matter what is in your hosts file, it should resolve to `127.0.0.1` regardless, so you're always safe with that URL configuration when working locally.

**EDIT:**

One other thing you might want to try in addition is replacing this call

```
local.host:3000/auth/twitter
```

with this

```
127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter
```

I only suggest this because if you erroneously modified something in your hosts file, that could be causing a conflict as well.  If you simply added lines to your hosts file, rather than modifying what was already there, you can also try replacing this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost local.host
```

with this

```
127.0.0.1 local.host
```

..as the first one looks malformed to me (two aliases instead of one).

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1 http://myExampleWebsite.com`

should be

`127.0.0.1 myExampleWebsite.com`

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix it. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: so after that change, are you trying: http://myExampleWebsite.com:3000/auth/twitter

Comment: No, I'm trying `local.host:3000/auth/twitter`.

Comment: Ok, well your host probably needs to match whatever the domain is for your twitter application settings, or you need to add local.host to your @Anywhere domains